# Error installing Typescript using npm

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-install

When I try installing Typescript with npm, I get an error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...latest","mocha":"late'
```

This is the content of the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'i',
1 verbose cli   'typescript',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.0.1
3 info using node@v10.0.0
4 verbose npm-session d4b7b23a6f27323f
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript 28ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for typescript@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...latest","mocha":"late'
9 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...latest","mocha":"late'
9 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
9 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
9 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
9 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:7)
10 verbose cwd /Users/Bayo/Documents/Personal/Learning/tstest
11 verbose Darwin 16.7.0
12 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "typescript" "--save-dev"
13 verbose node v10.0.0
14 verbose npm  v6.0.1
15 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...latest","mocha":"late'
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

My current npm version is 6.0.1
My current node version is 10.0.0

Comment: Hope you've tried executing `npm install -g typescript` to install it globally.

Comment: You have error in your package.json file. Please parse this file and fix error.

Comment: @DavidR Yes I have. Thank you.

Comment: @KamilNaja Thank you. I cleared my npm cache, updated npm and node and the error was gone.